# Does BEFORE INSERT trigger get executed for every row in "insert on duplicate key update" query

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

How does this work ? Does mysql invoke BEFORE INSERT trigger only in case of inserts or everytime an insert or update happens if the query to be run is as follows "

INSERT INTO tSomething VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ......

I want to update a column's value depending upon other col's values when inserting a row. However, I don't want this behaviour for updates.  The query which will be executed always would  be the one mentioned above. I chose INSERT AFTER for this. However, I can't update a col using AFTER INSERT TRIGGER as

SET NEW.score = NEW.score1 + NEW.score2 ;

I read somewhere that BEFORE INSERT trigger in this case would allow triggers to be fired everytime when above query is executed. Is this true ? If yes, how do I solve this problem using a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does mysql invoke AFTER INSERT trigger only in case of inserts or everytime an insert or update happens*

Right [from the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html):

> a BEFORE INSERT trigger will activate for every row, followed by either an AFTER INSERT trigger or both the BEFORE UPDATE and AFTER UPDATE triggers, depending on whether there was a duplicate key for the row

I'm not sure what exactly you are after.

The sentence "*However, I don't want this behaviour for updates*" confuses me somehow. If the only thing you have is an AFTER INSERT trigger, then it will not be fired if you run an UPDATE statement. And if your statement updates a row, it will fire an UPDATE trigger, not your INSERT trigger.

Comment: What I wanted to put across is that in my scenario, I am using the query mentioned above only for inserts and updates. To achieve the desired behavior of updating a col's value as function of other col's value in the row to be inserted, what should I use BEFORE INSERT or AFTER INSERT ? BEFORE INSERT trigger will get executed for every query "q" mentioned above. However, AFTER INSERT will get fired only for inserts executed through that sql. But with AFTER INSERT, I am not able to set the columns as "SET NEW.col = ....." since you can't set a NEW in after insert trigger.