# MySQL before trigger for INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - manual seems wrong?

Tags: mysql, upsert

I'm working with MySQL 5.7:

```
D:\>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
```

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html), the behavior of a BEFORE INSERT trigger is supposed to be:

> a BEFORE INSERT trigger activates for every row, followed by either an
>   AFTER INSERT trigger or both the BEFORE UPDATE and AFTER UPDATE
>   triggers, depending on whether there was a duplicate key for the row.

I take this to mean that the BEFORE INSERT is executed regardless of whether there's a duplicate key match, while AFTER INSERT and the UPDATE triggers are dependent on whether there's a key conflict. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709227/does-before-insert-trigger-get-executed-for-every-row-in-insert-on-duplicate-ke) repeats the same. However, I am not seeing this behavior. Here's what I did:

```
create table testtable (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  nickname varchar(40),    -- this is the natural key to be unique indexed
  name varchar(40),
  uuid varchar(36));       -- this is what I want to assign in the trigger

alter table testtable add unique index testtable_ux (nickname);
create trigger testtable_uid before insert on testtable for each row set
  new.uuid=uuid();

-- get some data
insert into testtable (nickname, name) values ('bob', 'Robert'), 
  ('fred', 'Frederick'), ('cha', 'Chauncey');
select * from testtable;

1   bob   Robert      06fb18be-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
2   fred  Frederick   06fb1a5d-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
3   cha   Chauncey    06fb1aec-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
```

Nice - each of the dudes has a unique UUID. OK now, according to the manual, this BEFORE INSERT trigger should get executed regardless of whether there's a duplicate key, so even when I get a duplicate key update, the UUID should be updated - right? Let's see:

```
insert into testtable (nickname, name) values ('fred', 'Alfred') 
  on duplicate key update name='Alfred';
3   88  16:39:32 ... 2 row(s) affected  0.032 sec

select * from testtable;
1   bob   Robert      06fb18be-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
2   fred  Alfred      06fb1a5d-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
3   cha   Chauncey    06fb1aec-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
```

Hm, the name was updated. Let's compare the UUIDs:

```
2   fred  Frederick   06fb1a5d-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
2   fred  Alfred      06fb1a5d-f87e-11e6-8e6f-0060737a7c01
```

The upsert was performed as expected, but the UUID was NOT regenerated. I've tried this with constant strings and get the same result.

Now, this is exactly what I would want to happen; a BEFORE INSERT that happens regardless of which branch of the upsert is taken seems pretty useless, or at least this behavior seems way more useful. But it seems counter to what the manual says. Any insights?

Comment: My guess: The new `uuid` is generated but not assigned. Why do you think it should? You tell exactly what should happen on duplikate key: `name='Alfred'`. So why do you expect the UUID to change?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for the thought but I have the "set" on there. It works during the initial insert - that's how the column gets populated in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BEFORE INSERT trigger is fired on duplicates. You can test it with a log table. I've added such a table to your code and modified the trigger to populate that table:

```
drop table if exists testtable;
create table testtable (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  nickname varchar(40),    -- this is the natural key to be unique indexed
  name varchar(40),
  uuid varchar(36));       -- this is what I want to assign in the trigger

alter table testtable add unique index testtable_ux (nickname);

drop table if exists testlog;
create table testlog (
  log_id int primary key auto_increment,
  nickname varchar(40),
  name varchar(40),
  uuid varchar(36)
);

drop trigger if exists testtable_uid;
delimiter //
create trigger testtable_uid before insert on testtable for each row
begin
  set new.uuid=uuid();
  insert into testlog (nickname, name, uuid) values (new.nickname, new.name, new.uuid);
end //
delimiter ;

insert into testtable (nickname, name) values ('bob', 'Robert'), 
  ('fred', 'Frederick'), ('cha', 'Chauncey');
select * from testtable;

insert into testtable (nickname, name) values ('fred', 'Alfred') 
  on duplicate key update name='Alfred';

select * from testtable;
select * from testlog;
```

You will see that the `testlog` table has 4 rows. The last one contains 'fred', 'Alfred' and a new UUID. That means the trigger has been fired. That also means a new UUID has been generated. But that UUID was not assigned to `testtable.uuid`. There is nothing in your code that tells to do so.

If you want the new UUID (generated in the trigger) to be assigned in the ON DUPLICATE part, you can acces it with `values(uuid)`:

```
insert into testtable (nickname, name) values ('fred', 'Alfred') 
  on duplicate key update 
    name='Alfred',
    `uuid`=values(`uuid`);
```

Comment: I see. What you are saying is that the trigger is running and the "new" record is being populated, but it doesn't actually do anything in the update case unless you bring it across in the UPDATE clause with the values() function. That makes sense. Thank you!